# Pixel art illustration app identification

Tags: illustration, pixel, mac, applications

While browsing through (genius) [Uno Moralez's Instagram account](https://www.instagram.com/unomoralez/?hl=en), I came across this screenshot from his computer with a set of illustration tools:

[image]

I am curious to know what app this is, if anyone knows.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's [TVpaint](http://www.tvpaint.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of investigation of the Instagram feed shows a few other images that are clearly [TVPaint](https://www.instagram.com/p/BEJn3wHhvyI/).

You can see the same panel at the top left of this screenshot:

[image: TVPaint]

http://www.tvpaint.com/